# Oracle SQL - Parameter in where condition to search two values from one

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have this case: A companys are identified in the I_COMPANY table with a unique code in IC_COMPANY_CODE column and a description in IC_COMPANY_DESC column.

**Example of records:**

- The IC_COMPANY_DESC = 'ATLANTA', is identified by two
  IC_COMPANY_CODE = 901 and 902.
- The IC_COMPANY_DESC = 'TORONTO', is identified by two
  IC_COMPANY_CODE = 903 and 904.

In this example query SQL, in the WHERE condition I want insert a parameter :IC_COMPANY_CODE = '901' and the query search result, must display in a dataset 901 and 902 records, how to write this query?

```
SELECT IC_COMPANY_CODE, IC_COMPANY_DESC
FROM I_COMPANY
WHERE IC_COMPANY_CODE  = :IC_COMPANY_CODE -- > how to insert 901 string and display result for 901 and 902?
```

Thanks

Comment: If there is not going to be more than a couple dozen duplicate codes you could make it a VARCHAR parameter and pass in a comma delimited string and google how to use that in a WHERE clause. Or if there's only ever going to be two records do a BETWEEN IC_COMPANY_CODE - 1 AND IC_COMPANY_CODE + 2

Answer (score 1):

You can get the description in a subquery and return all records with the description

```
SELECT IC_COMPANY_CODE, IC_COMPANY_DESC
FROM I_COMPANY
WHERE IC_COMPANY_DESC IN (SELECT IC_COMPANY_DESC
                          FROM I_COMPANY
                          WHERE IC_COMPANY_CODE  = :IC_COMPANY_CODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery ( assuming that you have only one row for a given `IC_COMPANY_CODE` )

```
SELECT *
FROM I_COMPANY
WHERE IC_COMPANY_DESC = 
                          ( 
                            SELECT IC_COMPANY_DESC
                            FROM I_COMPANY
                            WHERE IC_COMPANY_CODE = :IC_COMPANY_CODE
                          )
```

or join the table to itself:

```
SELECT C2.IC_COMPANY_CODE,  IC_COMPANY_DESC
FROM I_COMPANY C1
  INNER JOIN I_COMPANY C2
    USING (IC_COMPANY_DESC)
WHERE C1.IC_COMPANY_CODE = :IC_COMPANY_CODE
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve with apply this in WHERE condition:

```
DECODE(IC_COMPANY_CODE,'901','902','903','904',IC_COMANY_CODE)=:IC_COMANY_CODE
```

thanks for your support